# Admin section in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, admin

I'm having a hard time understanding how the CakePHP admin system works.

- Should all controllers who has an action which requires login include AuthComponent or just the one who handles the login/logout?
- <strike>Let's say I want to protect the add action of a controller. First I create `admin_add()` in the controller and then in the `beforeFilter()` method I check if `$this->Session->check('Auth.User')` is set a redirect based on this?</strike> Turns out it was better to just controll this with `$this->Auth->allow()`
- <strike>What is the easiest way to return to the URL the user was trying to access? Is there a better way than setting a session variable?</strike> Turns out it does this automagically :)

If someone has a good tutorial for this I would happily read it :)
I've already read [this](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/creating_an_admin_section_with_cakephp_updated) tutorial but I found it to be a little to basic and the CakePHP-docs are not that great on this topic either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Cake admin system as such. There is [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication) component and there is [Access Control List](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1242/Access-Control-Lists) component. You can use only Authentication component if you wish or you can use both of them. If you want to create your admin system from scratch follow [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application) tutorial. Or you can try already created admin panel - [PoundCake Control Panel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bancer/).

Answer (score 1):

we have created an admin system for cakePHP, works similar to the scaffolding but it's configurable and ready to deploy, check it at http://browniephp.org

Answer (score 0):

You can learn a lot from others codes, specially something like CakePHP Admin plugin at: https://github.com/Maldicore/Admin